# Open an ajax accordion pane when I click a button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, button, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

How to open accordion pane with fade transition effect when I click a button? I tried to code it in server side, it is working but there is no fadetransition.

here is my code...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Accordions.FadeTransitions = true;
        Accordions.SelectedIndex = 1;    
}
```

Comment: Is this an Accordion control from the AjaxControlToolkit library? Do you have any server code for button click besides changing accordion's selected pane?

Comment: yes that is a ajax control, that is my only code in button click.. @YuriyRozhovetskiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch selected pane on client.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="switchPane(1); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     function switchPane(index) {
          $find("<%= Accordions.ClientID %>_AccordionExtender").set_SelectedIndex(index);
     }
</script>
```

This approach disables server-side client event.